# What is the equivalent of folded in Lens.Family2?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

`folded :: Foldable f => Fold (f a) a` ([ref](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optics-core-0.3/docs/Optics-Fold.html#v:folded)) doesn't seem to have a definition in [Lens.Family2](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-family-2.1.0/docs/Lens-Family2.html); what is the appropriate way to use `folded` with Lens.Family2?

Comment: Have you tried `folding id`? I'm not too familiar with `lens-family`, but that smells about right.

Comment: @dfeuer I'll try it once I get it added to my lens test project, but how does that work, if the first argument to `folding` has type `s -> f a` and `id :: a -> a`? what would f be? I would guess `Identity` but I didn't realize it could be elided.

Comment: @bbarker that's a standard unification problem. It just means `s` must be the same type as `f a`. The `f` isn't magically vanishing. The thing that seems weird to me is that internally all `folding` does is run the provided function, then provide a `Fold` on the resulting value using something that has to be equivalent to the missing combinator you're looking for in the first place. Are you sure you don't want to just use `lens`? It doesn't hide its internals away from you like this.

Comment: @Carl Ah that's interesting, I should have seen that. Actually I confess I just switched to lens for a different reason ... it provides typeclasses for tuples having n or more elements, so you can use lenses beyond `_2` in the way you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

[`traverse_ :: (Foldable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f ()`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:traverse_) is lens-like.

```
folded :: Foldable t => Fold (t a) () a b
folded = traverse_
```

In fact, we know that the `f` is [`Phantom`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-family-core-2.1.0/docs/Lens-Family.html#t:Phantom) (from [`Fold`'s definition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-family-2.1.0/docs/Lens-Family2.html#t:Fold)) — `traverse_`'s return value doesn't actually contain any `()`s — so in theory you should be able to generalise `Folded`'s type using `coerce`:

```
folded :: Foldable t => Fold (t a) u a b
folded f = coerce . traverse_ f
```

(This should work for any `Fold s t a b`; the `t` and `b` parameters are always phantom. That's why [`lens`'s `Fold`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.2/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#t:Fold) only has two parameters.) Alas, it seems `coerce` is not exported by `Lens.Family2`, so you can't actually write this code. I would submit a feature request but I can't figure out where to send it.

Comment: FWIW, I believe `coerce = to id id`. That's no excuse, of course.